# Modifying properties fetched with Apollo GraphQL in vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo

I'm looking to format a date fetched via Apollo-GraphQL using the javascript Moment library. I'm using VueJS Apollo on the client side to make graphQL queries as such:

```
import { ALL_EVENTS } from '../constants/graphql.js'
import Event from './Event'
import moment from 'moment'

export default {
  name: 'EventList',
  data: () => ({
      events: [],
      loading: 0
    }),
  apollo: {
    events: ALL_EVENTS
  },
  components: {
    Event
  },
```

The apollo middleware returns a list of objects that contain an id, name, a startDate (UTC formatted string)
, and an endDate (also a UTC formatted string) property, among other properties added by apollo for it's use.

Whenever I try to make a computed property in VueJS using the object list from Apollo, it gives me a read-only error, but it seems to me like I'm creating a new object:

```
  computed: {
    eventsFormatted: function () {
      var out = this.events
      for (var i in out) {
        out[i].startDate = moment(out[i].startDate)
        out[i].endDate = moment(out[i].endDate)
      }
      return out
    }
  }
```

What do I need to do to make a duplicate of the array that I can modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `var out = this.events` the `out` var is now pointing to the same array of objects as `this.events`.

So if `this.events` is read-only, you'll need to make a copy of the array and if each object in the array is read-only you'll need to make a copy of each object as well.

Here's an example using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy the array and objects:

```
computed: {
  eventsFormatted() {
    let out = [...this.events];
    for (let i in out) {
      let item = {...out[i]};
      item.startDate = moment(item.startDate);
      item.endDate = moment(item.endDate);
      out[i] = item;
    }
    return out;
  }
}
```

The above makes a shallow copy of each object in the array. If you need to make a deep copy because of the structure of `this.events`, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).